# shortest_path_select() does not work

Tags: mesh, scripting, vertices

I have a List (verts_index_list) of 2 numbers that represents the index of 2 vertices. My goal is to collapse all vertices that are on the shortest path between those 2 Vertices. I looked in the blender api and saw that there is a function `shortest_path_select()` that should do what I want. So I wrote :

```
for v in verts_index_list:
    mesh.vertices[v].select = True
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_collapse()
```

but it does not work. The terminal prints the following warning :

> Warning: Path selection requires two matching elements to be selected

I don't understand... I selected exactly 2 vertices (`[v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]` gives me 2 Elements). So my question is: Do I have to update something before calling shortest_path_select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when I uses a BMesh instead of a Mesh type. When I uses the select_set(True) from BMVerts, the shortest_path_select() works fine.